# How to write Exceptions into custome file in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, scheduler

iam not able to write laravel exception into custome file.
for example: iam running a crone job in laravel 5.5 and i want to write any exception that comes by running the crone job want to save on custome file.
So i can track all exception with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cron jobs, if you are using Laravel's tasks, then you can schedule it like this :

```php
$schedule->command('do:something')
            ->daily()
            ->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/debug.log'));
```

you can replace the `sendOUtputTo` params to the path you want, just make sure that you have enough access to it.

Comment: But iam using $schedule->call() method can this work for same ?